# If no sorting order mentioned in SQL Server fetching data through EntityFramework gives different result

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a stored procedure which returns two records while executing directly from SQL Server Management Studio from which i am taking the top 1 record only.

Let say Record 1 & Record 2

When executing the stored procedure directly from SQL Server Management Studio it returns Record 1 but, calling the same procedure through Entity Framework returns Record 2. but if i'll sort the records it is giving correct result.

I just wanted to know is the default sorting order differs/matters in this case ? Is it different for both the cases ? Can anybody help me in this regard ?

Scenario : There are two Date columns let say Date1 & Date2, the ordering is made on Date1 column but for this scenario Date1 is same for two records. When i am calling the stored procedure directly the sort order is different Record1 then Record2 but calling the same at the same time through EntityFramework returns result like Record2 first and then Record1. My concern is why is it behaving differently same procedure when called from Entity Framework ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't give a sort order, the return of any statement is not ordered. That means theoretically, even two executions of the same statement in SQL server may produce differently ordered results.

For all pratical purposes, the sort order for "unordered" will likely stay the same, because it's just a computer program that always does the same, but it's not guaranteed.

If you don't give a sort order, the sort order is not guaranteed. It's not even guaranteed that it will be the same sort order on consecutive calls.

Comment: There are two Date columns let say Date1 & Date2, the ordering is made on Date1 column but for this scenario Date1 is same for two records. When i am calling the stored procedure directly the sort order is different Record1 then Record2 but calling the same at the same time through EntityFramework returns result like Record2 first and then Record1. My concern is why is it behaving differently same procedure when called from Entity Framework ?

Comment: Same answer: you did not specify a definite sort order for those two records, so the database and all in between are free to order those two records as they please. Define an order and you won't have that problem.

Comment: see the procedure always is returning in same order Record 1 then Record 2 but when same is called through entity framework  it is reversing the order i want to know the reason behind it... and it is happening in same order always.

Comment: nvoigt is completely right: if you don't include and `order by` in your stored procedure the DB will return the data in any order. You don't have to worry about why this happens. You simply have to worry about specifying an order in your stored procedure if it's important.

Comment: @SmrutiRanjanSahoo The reason won't help you. If your question is "why do they", the answer is "because they can". The question you need to ask is "how can I make it so this does not happen". And the answer is "specify a sort order that does not leave room for interpretation".

Comment: It is obvious to be curios to know why is it behaving differently only when called through Entity Framework. I appreciate your thinking that it will sort in any order when no sort order column is defined, but why is it reverse to direct call on procedure when called through entity framework ?(because the same procedure is being called both the scenario) :(